# Chrome Browser becomes laggy after an onClick event

Tags: jquery, onclick, mousemove, translate-animation, jquery-click-event

I am developing a parallax solution for my website which gets the mouse position every time the user moves the cursor. The problem that I ran into was that when I click anywhere on the document, the browser becomes laggy and jittery. I am able to log the position of the cursor without any lag however the display of movement on the document itself is choppy.

This is how I am getting the mouse position

```
this.onMove=function(posX, posY){
        bigX = $('#Stage').width();
        bigY = $('#Stage').height();
        console.log(posX+" - "+posY); //this is working properly in real-time
        posX = bigX/2 - (posX);
        posY = bigY/2 - (posY);
        for(i = 1; i<4; i++){    //the part that seems to be lagging
            $('.layer'+(i-1)+'').css({"-webkit-transform":"translate("+posX/50*i+"px,"+posY/50*i+"px)"});
        } 
    }

$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    this.onMove(e.pageX, e.pageY);
});
```

I also tried implementing the translations without a for loop but the result is the same. Is this a problem with the browser being bogged down or is there some sort of onclick event that may be stuck in a loop?

Comment: Seeing as the function and the for loop runs thousands of times every time you do a little movement with the mouse, the answer is likely "yes", the browser is bogged down.

Comment: Should I limit the number of polls per second to maybe alleviate some of the load?

Answer (score 1):

I made a test CopePen to understand the problem...
Since no code was provided.

While playing with it (I really had fun!), I found these things that should be considered.

1. Reduce the unnecessary calculations.
2. Limit decimals passed to `translate()`.
3. Disable mouse events in the "Stage" zone.

The two first are more about a performance concern...

But your main question was about mouse click "interference"... If I undestood well.
I noticed it in this very simple codePen!
One can't say there's a lot elements moving...

Still, it happens when you hold a mouse down and move, like a drag attempt.
Not always on the firsts... But it happens.

I fixed with `preventDefault()` and `return false` on these mouse events, inside the `#Stage` div.:

- `mousedown`
- `mouseup`
- `click`

So in [**this codePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/rrqOob), there are buttons that you can play with to see the effect of all this.
I hope you will like the effort made on this. ;)

**Here is my suggested `onMove` function:**
*(I removed the unnessary from what's in CodePen)*

```
function onMove(posX, posY){
    bigX = $('#Stage').width();
    bigY = $('#Stage').height();
    console.log(posX+" - "+posY); //this is working properly in real-time

    // Make most of your calculation ONCE
    posX = (bigX/2 - (posX))/50;
    posY = (bigY/2 - (posY))/50;

    // Translating layers now
    for(i = 1; i<4; i++){

        // Make the multiplication ONCE
        var thisLayerPosX = posX*i;
        var thisLayerPosY = posY*i;

        // Limit decimals
        thisLayerPosX = thisLayerPosX.toFixed(3);
        thisLayerPosY = thisLayerPosY.toFixed(3);

        var k = i-1;
        $('.layer'+k).css({"-webkit-transform":"translate("+thisLayerPosX+"px,"+thisLayerPosY+"px)"});

    }
}
```

I think that 3 decimals are ok.
It keeps the layers movement smooth.
1 or 0 makes it "pixel jumpy".

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I haven't implemented the decimal limiting yet, but it seems that would help some. In terms of the jittery action, that was due to the load as you might imagine, that's because I implemented a ease-in delay for each of the paralax elements. But I'll try this out soon and I'm glad you found my project interesting.